# Converting a C# DateTime to an SQL DateTime in input into the database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am trying to input these dates into a database from an excel spreadsheet. I have been able to get C# to read the date from the spreadsheet but now the SQL command won't allow me to insert these lines into the database. I need some help getting this formatted correctly for the database to except it.

In debug mode, this is the date: **'UpdateDate '3/28/2013 12:00:00 AM'** and this is what it looks like in the excel sheet: **3/28/2013  2:04:49 PM**. Below is my code:

```
private static bool SentenceMeasures_Update(DataRow dr)
{
   bool inserted = false;
   DateTime dt;
   Database pbkDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("PbKConnectionString");

   try
   {
      ChargeCode = dr["ChargeCode"].ToString().Trim();
      MeasureCode = dr["MeasureCode"].ToString().Trim();
      UpdateUserId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["UpdateUserId"].ToString().Trim()) ? "KSCONV" : dr["UpdateUserId"].ToString().Trim();
      UpdateDate = DateTime.TryParse(dr["UpdateDate"].ToString(), out dt) ? dt : DateTime.Now;
      DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@"Update tblCtStateChargeSentenceMeasures set  MeasureCode = '{1}', UpdateUserId = '{2}', UpdateDate '{3}' where ChargeCode = '{0}')", ChargeCode, MeasureCode, UpdateUserId, UpdateDate));

      pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
      inserted = true;
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
   }
   return inserted;
}
```

Comment: [Parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) is the answer

Comment: What is your db? What type of date field is in the db? Is it Date, timestamp, etc.?

Comment: What error is the above generating?

Comment: I was getting an SQL error. The first answer solved my issue. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Katherine I commented on the answer below is well, go ahead and check it off as solving your issue. Welcome to Stack Overflow! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you simply need an equals when setting `UpdateDate`? I.e.

```
... UpdateDate = '{3}' where ChargeCode = '{0}')", ...
               ^
```

You might also need to format the `DateTime` object to fit with what SQL expects. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: @Katherine Not a problem

Comment: @Katherine if this answered your question you should use the check mark on the left of the question to indicate so. :)

Answer (score 4):

A parametrized query is clearer, faster and safer. Clearer because the code is easier to read; faster because SQL will reuse the [query execution plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan); and safer because it will protect against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Below is your code refactored as a parameterized query:

```
DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(
    @"Update tblCtStateChargeSentenceMeasures set (MeasureCode = @MeasureCode 
    , UpdateUserId = @UpdateUserId
    , UpdateDate = @UpdateDate)
    where ChargeCode = @ChargeCode");
dcCommand.Parameter.Add("ChargeCode",ChargeCode);
dcCommand.Parameter.Add("MeasureCode",MeasureCode);
dcCommand.Parameter.Add("UpdateUserId",UpdateUserId);
dcCommand.Parameter.Add("UpdateDate",UpdateDate);

pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```